# Updating categories with too few observations

Tags: r, data.table

Please note that this question has been edited after r2evans' answer.

## Example data

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
vars_of_interest <- c("A", "B", "C")
vars_of_interest_obs_tot <- c("A_tot", "B_tot", "C_tot") 
adapted_BMstratum <- c("A_adapted_BMstratum", "B_adapted_BMstratum", "C_adapted_BMstratum")

full_df_bm <- fread("A B C BMstratum
                     1 NA NA 1110
                     23 1 2 1120
                     1 NA 1 1130
                     6 NA NA 1140
                     NA 1 1 1100
                     2 2 4 1110
                     NA 1 2 1120
                     NA 21 11 1130")

# Counting the current observations               
setDT(full_df_bm)[, (vars_of_interest_obs_tot) := lapply(vars_of_interest, function(x)  sum(!is.na(get(x)))),by = c("BMstratum")]
print(full_df_bm)

#     A  B  C BMstratum A_tot B_tot C_tot
# 1:  1 NA NA      1110     2     1     1
# 2: 23  1  2      1120     1     2     2
# 3:  1 NA  1      1130     1     1     2
# 4:  6 NA NA      1140     1     0     0
# 5: NA  1  1      1100     0     1     1
# 6:  2  2  4      1110     2     1     1
# 7: NA  1  2      1120     1     2     2
# 8: NA 21 11      1130     1     1     2

# The adapted strata start the same as the original
setDT(full_df_bm)[, (adapted_BMstratum):=BMstratum]
print(full_df_bm)

#     A  B  C BMstratum A_tot B_tot C_tot A_adapted_BMstratum B_adapted_BMstratum C_adapted_BMstratum
# 1:  1 NA NA      1110     2     1     1                1110                1110                1110
# 2: 23  1  2      1120     1     2     2                1120                1120                1120
# 3:  1 NA  1      1130     1     1     2                1130                1130                1130
# 4:  6 NA NA      1140     1     0     0                1140                1140                1140
# 5: NA  1  1      1100     0     1     1                1100                1100                1100
# 6:  2  2  4      1110     2     1     1                1110                1110                1110
# 7: NA  1  2      1120     1     2     2                1120                1120                1120
# 8: NA 21 11      1130     1     1     2                1130                1130                1130
```

## Updating the strata

For every variable in `adapted_BMstratum`, I would like to manually decide what to do when there are less than 2 observations for each of the variables `A`, `B`, or `C`.

```
for (i in seq_along(adapted_BMstratum)) {

  # If stratum 1110 has less than two observations change to 1120

  setDT(full_df_bm)[get(vars_of_interest_obs_tot[i])<2 & get(adapted_BMstratum[i])==1110, (adapted_BMstratum[i]):=1120 ,]  


  # Update the observations

  bygroup <- adapted_BMstratum[i]
  setDT(full_df_bm)[, (vars_of_interest_obs_tot) := lapply(vars_of_interest, function(x)  sum(!is.na(get(x)))),by = bygroup]

  # If stratum 1120 has less than two observations change to 1110

   setDT(full_df_bm)[get(vars_of_interest_obs_tot[i])<2 & get(adapted_BMstratum[i])==1120, (adapted_BMstratum[i]):=1110,]

  # Update the observations

  bygroup <- adapted_BMstratum[i]
  setDT(full_df_bm)[, (vars_of_interest_obs_tot) := lapply(vars_of_interest, function(x)  sum(!is.na(get(x)))),by = bygroup]


  # If stratum 1130 has less than two observations change to 1110

   setDT(full_df_bm)[get(vars_of_interest_obs_tot[i])<2 & get(adapted_BMstratum[i])==1120, (adapted_BMstratum[i]):=1110,]


  # Update the observations

  bygroup <- adapted_BMstratum[i]
  setDT(full_df_bm)[, (vars_of_interest_obs_tot) := lapply(vars_of_interest, function(x)  sum(!is.na(get(x)))),by = bygroup]

  # If any strata after has less than 2 observations, change them all to 1110

  setDT(full_df_bm)[get(vars_of_interest_obs_tot[i])<2 & (get(adapted_BMstratum[i])==1110 || get(adapted_BMstratum[i])==1120 || get(adapted_BMstratum[i])==1130), (adapted_BMstratum[i]):=1110,]    


  # Update the observations a last time

  bygroup <- adapted_BMstratum[i]
  setDT(full_df_bm)[, (vars_of_interest_obs_tot) := lapply(vars_of_interest, function(x)  sum(!is.na(get(x)))),by = bygroup]

}
```

This does however not give the desired outcome:

```
    A  B  C BMstratum A_tot B_tot C_tot A_adapted_BMstratum B_adapted_BMstratum C_adapted_BMstratum
1:  1 NA NA      1110     2     1     1                1110                1110                1110
2: 23  1  2      1120     1     2     2                1110                1120                1120
3:  1 NA  1      1130     1     1     2                1110                1110                1130
4:  6 NA NA      1140     1     0     0                1110                1110                1110
5: NA  1  1      1100     0     1     1                1110                1110                1110
6:  2  2  4      1110     2     1     1                1110                1110                1110
7: NA  1  2      1120     1     2     2                1110                1120                1120
8: NA 21 11      1130     1     1     2                1110                1110                1130
```

In addition it gives the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In get(adapted_BMstratum[i]) == 1110 || get(adapted_BMstratum[i]) ==  :
  'length(x) = 8 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
2: In get(adapted_BMstratum[i]) == 1110 || get(adapted_BMstratum[i]) ==  :
  'length(x) = 8 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
3: In get(adapted_BMstratum[i]) == 1110 || get(adapted_BMstratum[i]) ==  :
  'length(x) = 8 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

## Desired outcome

**NOTE: For `B_adapted_stratum` all have been changed to `1110` because `1110`,`1120` and `1130`, (if they exist) did not all have at least 2 observations.**

```
#     A  B  C BMstratum A_tot B_tot C_tot        A_adapted_BMstratum   B_adapted_BMstratum   C_adapted_BMstratum
# 1:  1 NA NA      1110     4     6     4                1110                1120                1120
# 2: 23  1  2      1120     4     6     4                1110                1120                1120
# 3:  1 NA  1      1130     4     6     2                1110                1120                1130
# 4:  6 NA NA      1140     1     0     0                1140                1140                1140
# 5: NA  1  1      1100     0     1     1                1100                1100                1100
# 6:  2  2  4      1110     4     6     4                1110                1120                1120
# 7: NA  1  2      1120     4     6     4                1110                1120                1120
# 8: NA 21 11      1130     4     6     2                1110                1120                1130
```

Note: The strata 1100 and 1140 should not be touched, but should not be removed either. This has to do with the fact that I need to add manual rules for these numbers separately. In the real data, there are way more numbers and rules, and I think it would become to messy to write everything out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start, though I don't know how to assign `1120` to `A_adapted_BMstratum` since the two categories are identical:

```r
full_df_bm[, c(adapted_BMstratum) := lapply(.SD, function(z) fifelse(z < 2, BMstratum[which.min(z)] , BMstratum)),
           .SDcols = vars_of_interest_obs_tot]
#    A_tot B_tot C_tot BMstratum A_adapted_BMstratum B_adapted_BMstratum C_adapted_BMstratum
#    <int> <int> <int>     <int>               <int>               <int>               <int>
# 1:     1     2     1      1110                1110                1110                1110
# 2:     1     1     2      1120                1110                1120                1120
```

Comment: The decision to choose one over another when both have only one observation seems completely arbitrary to me. Is there some unspoken logic to preferring one over the other?

Comment: I don't think that's the best way to go. This can likely be resolved if you explain the logic behind choosing (say) 1120 over 1110 when they are otherwise identical.

Comment: You still leave the logic of choice out of your discussion. Is it just an order, where 1110  always goes to 1120 (regardless of 1120's count), and anything else goes to 1110?

Comment: In your newest data, row 4 (1140) has `A_tot==1` and the others 0, yet its `*_adapted_BMstratum` remain unchanged as 1140. Similarly, row 5 is inconsistent. I can't help if your data is inconsistent with your desired output and I cannot understand the logic of choosing replacement values.

Comment: That is how I thought it would be easier to do it. Just add 1110 to 1120 and then check if if 1120 hopefully has enough observations.

Comment: 1140 and 1100 should be untouched (see the note at the bottom of the post). This has to do with the fact that other numbers need other changes (which I do not all want to write out)

Comment: I really don't know anymore. Your desired output has completely different `*_tot` values as in the raw data, with no discussion about why they would change other than the otherwise-silent introduction of "updating values" in your code, though I don't see a pattern yet in how that's supposed to iterate over `A,B,C` yet see changes in `A_tot,B_tot,C_tot`, nor how aggregating full group-column values and repeating across the group is meaningful. Sorry, Tom, I'm utterly confused and uncertain as to the goal, and I'm out of time. Good luck.